# Select TOP N values in WHERE

Tags: sql, teradata

I am looking for the way to choose rows containing top N values in certain field. For example, I would like to chose rows for the latest and second to latest dates in the table. So,  I could use that:

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3, report_date FROM My_Table
WHERE report_date = (SELECT MAX(report_date) from My_Table)
OR report_date = (
SELECT MAX(report_date from My_Table 
WHERE report_date < (SELECT MAX(report_date) FROM My_Table)
)
```

Ok, it works as expected. But for, let say, top 5 dates the code would be very sophisticated. I have tried something like that:

```
Select  * from  AL_CHECKER 
where REPORT_DATE in (
select top 2 MAX(REPORT_DATE) from AL_CHECKER order by max(report_date) desc
)
```

But I have just learned that TOP N is not supported in subquery. So, what is supported and how to make as easy to read as possible?

Comment: Have you considered using [QUALIFY with ROW_NUMBER](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/hlo1472240810308.html) ?

Comment: You could use row_number() over (partition by ... order by ) and then limit to top 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon's query using `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` works as expected.

Regarding the *Top N option is not supported in subquery* error, there's a workaround. It explicitly states *Subquery* (because it might be Correlated), but doesn't mention *Derived Tables*, thus nesting the Subquery in a Derived Table works:

```
SELECT *
FROM AL_CHECKER
WHERE report_date IN
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM 
    (
      SELECT TOP 2 report_date
      FROM AL_CHECKER
      GROUP BY 1
      ORDER BY 1
    ) AS dt
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use window functions and a subquery or `qualify` in Teradata:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
qualify row_number() over (order by date desc) <= 5;
```

If you wanted to include ties, you would use either `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Or, you can just use `top`:

```
select top 5 t.*
from my_table t
order by date desc;
```

Comment: But I don't need top 5 rows, but rows with top 5 values in certain column.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's query does just that...it will give you rows with the "top 5" (i.e. maximum) date values.

If you want to order based on other values in a different column, just change the ORDER BY field and the sort_order (ASC/DESC)